# Spring Boot vs JOOQ vs Unix socket

Tags: spring-boot, jooq, google-cloud-run, unix-socket

I have Spring boot app with JOOQ for working with PostrgesDB.
This app must be running on Google cloud. If I deploy this as AppEngine Flex all works without problem.

Now I need deploy and run this app into the google run. Way for connect Cloud Run with PostgresDB is described https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run#public-ip-default_1.

My problem is in combination using of JOOQ and com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory
Do you have some solution?

Comment: Sorry - but what is the actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

jOOQ offers means of executing queries via JDBC, and starting from jOOQ 3.15 via [R2DBC](https://r2dbc.io). If your installation doesn't support a JDBC or R2DBC driver but requires more low level interaction, you can't use jOOQ to execute SQL directly, but you can still extract your SQL strings and bind variables from jOOQ queries and implement the glue code to your `SocketFactory` yourself. An example is provided here where [jOOQ queries are executed on a JPA `EntityManager`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/alternative-execution-models/using-jooq-with-jpa/using-jooq-with-jpa-native/):

```java
// query is any jOOQ query
String sql = query.getSQL();
List<Object> binds = query.getBindValues();
```